# Stream closed Exception

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filestream, graphicimage

I'm getting `Stream is closed Exception` when I'm going to save the uploaded image.
I'm tring to preview `graphicImage` of uploaded image the before save. This operation is working. But I can't save the image. Here is my code:

```
private InputStream in;
private StreamedContent filePreview;
// getters and setters

public void upload(FileUploadEvent event)throws IOException { 
    // Folder Creation for upload and Download
    File folderForUpload = new File(destination);//for Windows
    folderForUpload.mkdir();
    file = new File(event.getFile().getFileName());
    in = event.getFile().getInputstream();
    filePreview = new DefaultStreamedContent(in,"image/jpeg");
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public void setFilePreview(StreamedContent fileDownload) {
    this.filePreview = fileDownload;
}

public StreamedContent getFilePreview() {
    return filePreview;
}

public void saveCompanyController()throws IOException{
    OutputStream out  = new FileOutputStream(getFile());
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    FileMasterDO fileMasterDO=new FileMasterDO();
    fileMasterDO.setFileName(getFile().getName());
    fileMasterDO.setFilePath(destination +file.getName());
    fileMasterDO.setUserMasterDO(userMasterService.findUserId(UserBean.getUserId()));
    fileMasterDO.setUpdateTimeStamp(new Date());
    in.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    fileMasterService.save(filemaster);
}
```

The bean is in the session scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to read an `InputStream` twice (the first time is in `DefaultStreamedContent` constructor of upload method and the second time is in the copy loop of the save method). This is not possible. It can be read only once. You need to read it into a `byte[]` first and then assign it as a bean property so that you can reuse it for both the `StreamedContent` and the save.

Make sure that you *never* hold external resources such as `InputStream` or `OutputStream` as a bean property. Remove them all from the current and other beans where applicable and use `byte[]` to hold the image's content as property.

In your particular case, you need to fix it as follows:

```
private byte[] bytes; // No getter+setter!
private StreamedContent filePreview; // Getter only.

public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = event.getFile().getInputStream();

    try {
        IOUtils.read(input, bytes);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
    }

    filePreview = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), "image/jpeg");
    // ...
}

public void saveCompanyController() throws IOException {
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(getFile());

    try {
        IOUtils.write(bytes, output);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note: `IOUtils` is from Apache Commons IO, which you should already have in the classpath as it's a dependency of `<p:fileUpload>`.

Comment: i'm not going to save the image in database.Just i need to save the path only.

Comment: I'm not sure what this comment has to do with the question and answer. Did you *understand* the concrete problem? You're reading an `InputStream` twice (once in `upload()` method and once in `saveCompanyController()` method). This is **not** possible. You can read it only once. Read it into a `byte[]` which you can then read/reuse as many times as you want.

Comment: I expanded the answer with a concrete kickoff example of how to fix it properly.